# MVC 3 Remote Validation of object not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

I realize this question has already been asked plenty of times. However none of the solutions worked for me.

The problem:

I have an object:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    [Remote("MyAction", "MyController")]
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
}
```

And a model:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public SomeObject MyObject { get; set; }
}
```

and my action:

```
public JsonResult MyAction(DateTime MyDate)
{
     //do some validation here
}
```

When the validation kicks in, because its a complex object it sends a URL like this:

```
http://localhost/MyController/MyAction?MyObject.MyDate=xxxxxxxx
```

Obviously this means that my action wont pick up the date because the parameter name does not match the querystring name.

I've searched far and wide and saw lots of suggestions - all of which I've tried but none have worked. The following was what I tried:

Using the bind attribute

```
public JsonResult MyAction([Bind(Prefix = "MyObject")]DateTime MyDate)
```

and

```
public JsonResult MyAction([Bind(Prefix = "MyObject.MyDate")]DateTime MyDate)
```

the date just comes back as null

Using the model or the object as the parameter type

```
public JsonResult MyAction(SomeObject myObject)
```

and

```
public JsonResult MyAction(SomeModel myModel)
```

`MyDate` always ends up as MinValue, but the parameters (SomeModel or SomeObject) are not null

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Are there any incantations I have to chant prior to running, or perhaps does it have to be sunny outside? This seems to be far more work for a common scenario than expected.

Comment: I should note that I saw the solution where you can access it directly for the querystring using `Request["..."]` but I want to avoid using magic strings.

Comment: I should also note that the date is parseable - as in if i get the date via the `Request` method and parse it, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the problem is not what I thought it was. The problems lie with the jQuery UI Datepicker, which is sending the PREVIOUS value through to the action and with my culture settings. The datepicker is formatted with `dd/MM/yy` but MVC tries to interpret that as a US style `MM/dd/yy` even though `DateTime.Parse` parses it correctly. Thats the main reason why the date comes back as null. I will be writing questions around those two issues.

As for the solution - using the following does actually work:

```
public JsonResult MyAction(SomeObject myObject)
```